# Java generic interface with one parameter has actually two

Tags: java, interface

I recently found java code similar to this:

```
public interface DemoInterface<T> extends Serializable
{
    <V> void demoMethod(Collection<V> someValues, SomeType<V, T> moreValues);
}
```

Since i already read some advice on interfaces and never found a situation like this i ask here: The interface statement only mentions `<T>`. What does the `<V>` mean?

If you know the answer please be patient and give example how to use this interface and an implementation of the interface and the demoMethod.

Thank you.

Comment: `V` is a type parameter that usually stands for "value".

Comment: `V` is this is been used to bind the `Collection` contents with the `SomeType`

Comment: @MarounMaroun But the interface does only mention T - not V.

Comment: Think of the `<V>` as unbound inside the body of the interface. Instead, it is used as a generic parameter for the generic method defined inside the generic interface.

Comment: The interface has one parameter. The method has another. There are generic interfaces and generic methods - in this case you have a generic method inside a generic interface.

Comment: I expected that demoMethods with different types yield different types of DemoInterface implementations, but it does not in java. Looking at it again it's just "Generic Method".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just offer an example:

```
DemoInterface<Type> demo = new DemoInterface<>() {
 <V> void demoMethod(Collection<V> someValues, SomeType<V, Type> moreValues) {
  Type type = new Type();
  foreach(V value: someValues) {
   Type subtype = moreValues.doSomething(value);
   type.concat(subtype);
  }
  System.out.printf("result: %s%n", type); 
 }
};

SomeType<ValueA, Type> someA = new SomeType<>();
SomeType<ValueB, Type> someB = new SomeType<>();
List<ValueA> listA = new Arraylist<>(); // add some elements
List<ValueB> listA = new Arraylist<>(); // add some elements

demo.demoMethod(listA, someA);    
demo.demoMethod(listB, someB);
```

Answer (score 1):

`V` is an additional generic type parameter that applies only to `demoMethod`, unlike `T` which applies to all the methods of this interface.

Comment: I had this in mind already, but struggle understanding because the interface does not mention v.

Comment: @Matthias The `<V>` before the method introduces a method specific generic type parameter.